# Tor browser not launching after installation on Kali

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, linux, tor-install, kali-linux

This is my first post on the community, any help is much appreciated.

I did install both tor and torbrowser-launcher on my Kali machine, but when I tried to run the command "torbrowser-launcher", it shows the small dialog box saying installing and verifying signature, then I get the following message and it's not loading the tor browser:

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/agent77_kali/.local/share/torbrowser/tbb/x86_64/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/TorBrowser/Docs/ChangeLog.txt'
zsh: IOT instruction torbrowser-laun

I can see that the Tor Browser and Tor Browser Launcher settings has been installed as it's in the applications, screenshot below.
If I open the Tor browser from the application section, the verifying signature dialog box pops up and after few seconds, close.
And if I open the Tor Browser Launcher settings, the details can also be seen from the screenshot below.

What can I do to resolve the error please.
Thanks for the help in advance.
[image: tor-launcher-setting]
[image: tor-browser-launcher-error]
[image: tor-browser-loading-signature]

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem and I realized it's just a dumb syntax error.
You can see in your files that inside "/home/agent77_kali/.local/share/torbrowser/tbb/x86_64/" there's a directory called "tor-browser" instead of "tor-browser_en-US".

Changing that directory's name fixed the problem for me:

```
mv tor-browser/ tor-browser_en-US/
```

(This command only works if you are in /home/agent77_kali/.local/share/torbrowser/tbb/x86_64/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Tiago, thanks that works. I never thought of that.